# Ops Manager Install in Windows and connect to mongod instance started in linux

Tags: mongodb, ops-manager, mongodb-4.0

Can we install ops manager in windows and connect to mongodb instance started in Linux operating system? Does ops manager installation on windows require separate installation of mongoDB instance on windows also? 
Can we install ops manager on linux and access it from windows using URL?Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can we install ops manager in windows and connect to mongodb instance
>   started in Linux operating system?

No, I have not done as practically , as per my knowledge due to platform & their [connection string](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) used to access the Ops Manager Application Database.

> Does ops manager installation on windows require separate installation
>   of mongoDB instance on windows also?

No, Because, the databases require dedicated MongoDB instances. Do not use MongoDB installations that store other data. The Backup Database is required only if you will use the Backup feature.

> Can we install ops manager on linux and access it from windows using
>   URL?

Yes,For example you are going to access ops manager through the following URL

```
http://<OpsManagerHost>:8080
```

You have to make sure that the host is the fully qualified domain name of the server.

For further your ref [here](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/tutorial/install-on-prem-windows/#single-instance-install-procedure) , [here](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/tutorial/install-on-prem-with-rpm-packages/) and [here](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/reference/configuration/#conf-mms-properties)